# Erasing all operating systems on a dual boot

Tags: uninstall, dualboot

I recently bought a new laptop and installed both Ubuntu and Windows. It has been super buggy, I'll spare you the details but I think a full reinstall of both operating systems might work. However, I have never uninstalled/erased a dual boot system and I'm afraid I'm gonna screw something up. Does Windows diskpart's clean command just clear the entire disk and remove all partitions? I'm kind of clueless, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: clean command erases the partition table (first 2k of the hard drive), it does not erase data, but you dont need to do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it is very surprising to have a "bugged" system during a dual boot, to the point of having to completely reset.
but as you do not specify these ... bugs, I limit myself to the final question.

Yes "diskpart clean" removes all partitioning information from the selected hard drive, so it is strongly recommended to be sure that you have backed up what you want to keep before doing so, and be sure to select the right hard drive. (if you have more than one)

The real data delete was made by "dispart clean All", but not necessairy

Note that the use of "diskpart" is not compulsory, and that you can delete its partitions when reinstalling your systems.

For a Windows / Linux dual boot, it is preferable to install Windows 10 first, leaving room for a new partition, then install Ubuntu

There is a lot of documentation on this sort of thing on the net.
ex: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/